# SonarQube 6.5 - Not able to configure the SQL Server Database

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web

I installed the latest version of SonarQube 6.5 and have been able to get the SonarQube server up and running. I have my SQL Server database named ‘Sonar’ created with a user named ‘SonarUser’ and have given it admin rights. I have changed the collation to be case-sensitive (CS) and accent-sensitive (AS). 
I have downloaded the jdbc driver and put it in the correct folders.
Followed the steps mentioned here - https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server

However I am not able to make either Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication to work. The database is still empty, and do not see the tables/indexes in there.

I am making the below changes to the ‘sonar.properties’ file – 1 at a time – but it does not work

**SQL Authentication**

```
sonar.jdbc.username=SonarUser 
sonar.jdbc.password=SonarUser
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Sonar
```

**Windows Authentication**

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Sonar;
integratedSecurity=true
```

When I make any change to the ‘sonar.properties’ file and then start the Sonar Server, it fails with the following error –

> 2017.10.03 16:59:09 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Sonarqube-6.5\temp
>   2017.10.03 16:59:09 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Sonarqube-6.5\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer
>   C:\Sonarqube-6.5\temp\sq-process1211130103830390174properties
>   2017.10.03 16:59:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
>   2017.10.03 16:59:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Sonarqube-6.5\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;C:\Sonarqube-6.5\lib\jdbc\mssql\mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar
>   org.sonar.server.app.WebServer
>   C:\Sonarqube-6.5\temp\sq-process7396503632227644033properties
>   2017.10.03 16:59:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
>   2017.10.03 16:59:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
>   2017.10.03 16:59:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped <-- Wrapper Stopped

If I undo the changes in ‘sonar.properties’ file, and run the StartSonar.bat - the server runs fine.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please provide the web.log output -> as it seems like there we find the cause!

Comment: @Sammy please: [1]-uncomment #sonar.log.level=DEBUG in file INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY/sonarqube-6.5/conf/sonar.properties [2]-delete all file in INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY/sonarqube-6.5/logs [3]-run  server [4]-post all file generated in directory logs

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response. i was able to identify the issue. I was using an older version of SQL Server Express instance, which is not supported by the newer version of SonarQube. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to get through this error and was able to configure my SQL Database. In the web.log file, I saw the error message -

> Unsupported mssql version: 10.0. Minimal supported version is 11.0.

Basically I was running an older version of SQL Server, which was causing this error. Once I created a database in SQL Server 2014 with this above steps, I was able to run the SonarQube instance without any issues. All the required tables got created in the database. I also confirmed that there are records inserted into the tables as you run SonarQube against my projects.

Comment: This shows again and again that detailed inspection of log files is crucial for troubleshooting.